# Should I be optimizing CSS for a specific browser and screen resolution?

Tags: html, css

I am new to the world coding as well as CSS and would like to know if I should optimize CSS to a specific browser.

Also should I be concerned about screen resolution? If so what screen sizes should I be targetting especially if I have very little information about the end-users e.g. will they using laptops with smaller screen resolutions in comparison to desktop, will they be using netbooks, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your site to assume a certain minimum size. say, 800x600 or 1024x768 and enforce that with min-width/min-height directives. If you want to support mobile browsers, have an alternate layout that assumes a much smaller screen

But as far as assuming sizes, there's very little you can do without running a sniffing bug in Javascript that reports back to your site (or use something like Google Analytics). Until you've got some statistics, pick a decent middle-ground (1680x1050 / 1280x1024 should handle most desktop users these days) and then adjust later as needed.

Comment: @Marc B - Thanks. Would I set the min-width using % or pixels? Why choose one over the other? Would I set min-width to the entire body or just the container?

Comment: @MarcB - I disagree.  You should still consider@ 1024x768  anyone using a smart device/netbook/bad eye sight will appreciate it.

Comment: I just checked my site, and 1024x768 is the largest % of visitors at 31%

Comment: @Peanuts: Use pixels since you're targeting a computer-centric audience. Percentages are relative, so `min-width: 50%` comes out as "one-half the width of your screen, always" (or 1/2 the width of the container holding the element/document in question).

Comment: @Doug, fair enough, once tablets are widespread enough to be a going concern. But right now the world's tablet audience is a drop in the bucket of desktop users.

Answer (score 1):

Run google analytics on the site.  Find out the real usage for your site.  Maybe everyone has 24" monitors @ 1920x1080

[image]

# 2 is very skewed since internal traffic (employees) all have 1280x1024 and are very heavy site users.

Comment: Assuming the page I am designing has not had a web presence or never bothered to use analytics to measure traffic, etc, how would I approach the design of the layout?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - I attached my sites, traffic report. Our site is completely un demographic specific-ish, since anyone who owns property might use it.  You could use this graph as a starting point.  But you are correct, in you need a site to run analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I've been following the [320 and up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/) project. From a best practice point-of-view, it might we worth looking at:-

> ‘320 and Up’ prevents mobile devices
>   from downloading desktop assets by
>   using a tiny screen’s stylesheet as
>   its starting point.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it though due to my lack of knowledge I am unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I just usually design sites at a width of around 800 - 880px, no wider than that, Think [my site](http://www.bakerdesigns.co.uk) is 880px.

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you stick with 800 - 800px?

Comment: Are your layouts designed to be liquid?